# Magento 2, get order id in order view page in admin panel, if possible through session

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, view

I need to retrieve my custom column information from "`sales_order_item`" table. I'm having challenge to get the order id. How to get order id in order view page in admin panel?

I need $orderId in below code?

```
public function getOrderItemAgreementDeccription()

        {
           $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
           $_order = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item')->load($orderId);
           $getAgreementDeccription =  $_order->getAgreementDeccription();


        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Order view page in admin panel, you can get Order Id from URL like,

```
$orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
```

Comment: RIGHT...I'd totally forgotten this ;)

Comment: Cool!! Thank you this works great! Just what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can get order id by following param `order_id` as you can in url `sales/order/view/order_id/2`

```
$order_id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
```